# flutter packages get ERORR 66 linux : Could not decompress gz stream Connection closed while receiving data, path = ''

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

I can't run flutter packages get it give me this error , i'm using Ubuntu 20.04 lts:

Could not decompress gz stream Connection closed while receiving data, path = ''
Running "flutter pub get" in myApp ...
pub get failed (66; Could not decompress gz stream Connection closed while receiving data,
path = '')

Answer (score 1):

it's all about good internet connection !
once i get a good internet connection i didn't get the error again,
and if you are in country flutter not in your region you can use vpn .[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L5VSI.png)